# Wordpress Revo Theme - Mega menu issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't able to edit mega menu. I tried all possible ways.

I have attached all screenshots for refernce.
[image: Frontend Section for Mega Menu]

[image: Backend Screenshot for Menu]

[image: Backend Screenshot 2 for Menu]

Comment: What you mean by can't edit? any error?

Comment: I couldn't find option in wp dashboard to edit that accesories menu.

Comment: Can't you see this menu option under appearance > Menu ?

Comment: Yes, But I can't see option for accessories (Mega Menu)

Comment: I can't understand you :(

Comment: Please see 3rd image attached. I can't find that Mega Menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143673/discussion-between-sazzad-hussain-and-ashkar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to mega-menu page, there you can see the menu item to edit